# Long-Running Looping VBA script

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have a VBA script that runs through one file using 2 fields to look up values in 2 other files.  One brings back 5 different values and the other brings back 1 file.  When I tested it the VBA script took about 10 minutes to process 10k records on the original file.  When I delivered it to the client they had it run with about 900k records and it gave up after it ran for almost 20 hours.

They were manually doing this using VLOOKUPs but it took 6-8 hours for those to update.  The VBA script needs to be faster than that.

Comment: Needs more detail to provide any really useful suggestions.  In general in-memory processing will be fastest, but it's impossible from your question to be more specific.  A good start would be to post your current code.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for Access or SQL.  That's a lot of formulas to run.  A database program will have infinitely faster results.